# For loop exiting after 1 cycle

Tags: iphone, for-loop

I'm trying to make an iPhone app that detects duplicate contacts. I've made a for loop to loop through an array of all the contacts (people) but it only seems to work once.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < [people count]; i++)
    {   
                    ABRecordRef person = (ABRecordRef)[people objectAtIndex:i];
                    ABRecordRef person2;

                    NSString *firstname = (NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
                    NSString *lastname = (NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

                    NSLog(@"Firstname = %@", firstname);
                    NSLog(@"People count = %i", [people count]);

                    for (int j = 0; i < [people count]; i++)
                    {
                        person2 = (ABRecordRef)[people objectAtIndex:i];

                        if (j != i 
                            && [firstname isEqualToString:(NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person2, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)] 
                            && [lastname isEqualToString:(NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person2, kABPersonLastNameProperty)])
                        {
                            //duplicate is found
                            NSString *name = firstname;
                            name = [name stringByAppendingString:@" "];
                            name = [name stringByAppendingString:lastname];
                            [duplicates addObject:name];
                        }
                    }
}
NSLog(@"Exited loop!");
```

The outputs of the NSLog is this:

```
Firstname = Bob
People count = 3
Exited loop!
```

I tried substituting [people count] for 3, but got the same output. I don't have a break; statement anywhere in my code, so I don't know what the problem is...

Comment: As a side note, you could memoize your algorithm and change this from O(n squared) to O (n log n) efficiency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing and incrementing `i` in the inner loop.

Also, the inner loop should only test values of j that are less than (or alternatively, greater than) i. Currently, you are testing every pair twice.

```
int n = [people count]; // minor perf improvement
for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    ...
    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        ...
```

This also obviates the `j != i` test.

For an even further improvement, instead of the inner loop, add people's names to an `NSSet` and test membership of that set to identify duplicates. This is much faster for large populations.

Comment: Thanks! Dumb mistake on my part... That optimization will help, and rid me of a bug I knew I was going to need to put in extra code for later.

Answer (score 1):

You're testing and incrementing the `i` variable in the inner loop; it should be `j`:

```
for (int j = 0; j < [people count]; j++)
```

When looping like this, I generally use the other for-style looping:

```
for (Person *p in peopleArray) {
  // do something amazing here with p.
}
```

Comment: more accidently testing and incrementing...

Answer (score 1):

Yep, `for (int j = 0; i < [people count]; i++)`

It's a mistake we all make, more often than we want to admit.